# using React Native with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, react-native, laravel-5

I need help regarding how to create an **react native app** of a project which is already made in the **Laravel framework**.

As I am going to make a Laravel website. So I also want to create an IOS and Android app for it.

Can anyone suggest me something for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a layman's terms:

Laravel is a backend framework, react-native is a frontend framework - they will only be interacting through API's.

You will be creating API's (laravel controllers that return json objects instead of websites) and then call them from the react-native app.

lastly, you will write code in js and have it execute around the json objects that you received from the API to create app elements.

User's interaction within the app will use a similar set of API's to send the data back to your laravel framework (works quite similar to forms)

Comment: this means I have to create the design separately for both application website and app

Comment: you can reuse the design between the laravel website and the app, but you will have to write code separately. Using react native will save you from having to write the design three times: web, android, ios, and instead you will only need to write web + react native.

Answer (score 1):

Basically laravel is a backend programming language framework and its PHP so definately laravel most important thing is to build API's.

And the another side we have react which is the latest framework of javascript which is made up of Facebook for front end side.

So React developer + laravel developer = Full Stack developer

so basically you have two sides web or App 
you build API's for the help of controllers and that controllers gives the response in 
JSON's format when the App developer call the controllers

your controllers are attached your module and your your module are connected to your
database.

you write a code of javascript inside of Json's

Comment: Hi, I'm very curious. So where can I find the documentation for connecting react native + laravel?

P.S: I'm a complete newbie...

Comment: you can easily find your solution in here sir   https://appdividend.com/2018/03/21/how-to-connect-react-native-application-with-laravel-api/

Comment: my pleasure sir